# Select datatype of the field in postgres

Tags: postgresql

How do I get datatype of specific field from table in postgres ?
For example 
I have the following table,
  student_details (
       stu_id   integer,
       stu_name varchar(30 ),
       joined_date timestamp 
   );

In this using the field name / or any other way, I need to get the datatype of the specific field. Is there any possibility ?

Comment: Also asked & answered https://stackoverflow.com/q/20194806/65458

Answer (score 266):

You can get data types from the [information_schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/infoschema-columns.html) (8.4 docs referenced here, but this is not a new feature):

```
=# select column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns
-# where table_name = 'config';
    column_name     | data_type 
--------------------+-----------
 id                 | integer
 default_printer_id | integer
 master_host_enable | boolean
(3 rows)
```

Comment: So simple and nice! Now I can replace the current query that I found that is 310 characters (without the table name), 4 table join, not schema aware, expensive, and that gives 'int4' and others as types instead of integer. Thank you!

Comment: PostgreSQL allows you to have the same table name (even an identical table) in multiple schemas. The robust way to write that WHERE clause considers that possibility: `where table_catalog = ? and table_schema = ? and table_name = ?;` But this information_schema view doesn't consider that the DDL might have used [domains](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createdomain.html).

Comment: This will not give you the type of array, so it has to be used along with `pg_typeof`

Comment: You should use `character_maximum_length` for varchar and similar types. Also probably you might want to get numeric precision... This should show both: `select column_name, data_type, coalesce(character_maximum_length, numeric_precision) as precision from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'record';`

Comment: if you want them in order add `ORDER BY ordinal_position` like this `SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns where table_name = '{table_name}' ORDER BY ordinal_position;`

Answer (score 232):

You can use the [pg_typeof()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) function, which also works well for arbitrary values.

```
SELECT pg_typeof("stu_id"), pg_typeof(100) from student_details limit 1;
```

Comment: this returns a row per record in table. Don't run it if you have millions of records

Comment: This works beautifully if you need to get the determine the type of a calculation. eg, `SELECT pg_typeof( date_part( 'year', now() ) ) AS expr` probably is different from what you'd expect.

Comment: the clever thing here is that `pg_typeof` works for fields coming out of stored procedures, for which the backend table, if it even exists, is unknown/unclear.  `select state, qstart, pg_typeof(qstart) as ty_qstart from listconn()`.  information_schema wouldn't help much here.

Comment: @JLPeyret exactly! with I could upvote multiple times

Comment: Doesn't show number of characters for varchar though. Just shows "character varying". You can get that from `information_schema.columns`.

Comment: @Saarang according to docs on `LIMIT`, "the query optimizer takes LIMIT into account when generating query plans" so it will mostly likely not check all rows.

Answer (score 67):

Try this request :

```
SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE 
table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE' AND column_name = 'YOUR_FIELD';
```

Comment: `table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE' AND column_name = 'YOUR_FIELD';`

Comment: If you have several tables with same names it can be necessary to include table_schema in the request: 

table_schema='YOUR_SCHEMA' AND table_name='YOUR_TABLE' AND column_name='YOUR_FIELD'

Answer (score 50):

run `psql -E` and then `\d student_details`

Answer (score 20):

If you like 'Mike Sherrill' solution but don't want to use psql, I used this query to get the missing information:

```
select column_name,
case 
    when domain_name is not null then domain_name
    when data_type='character varying' THEN 'varchar('||character_maximum_length||')'
    when data_type='numeric' THEN 'numeric('||numeric_precision||','||numeric_scale||')'
    else data_type
end as myType
from information_schema.columns
where table_name='test'
```

with result:

```
column_name |     myType
-------------+-------------------
 test_id     | test_domain
 test_vc     | varchar(15)
 test_n      | numeric(15,3)
 big_n       | bigint
 ip_addr     | inet
```

Comment: In my DB at least if character_maximum_length, numeric_precision, numeric_scale contain NULL value, myType will be empty. So we should add COALESCE for these 3 fields

Answer (score 10):

The information schema views and pg_typeof() return incomplete type information. Of these answers, `psql` gives the most precise type information. (The OP might not need such precise information, but should know the limitations.)

```
create domain test_domain as varchar(15);

create table test (
  test_id test_domain, 
  test_vc varchar(15), 
  test_n numeric(15, 3), 
  big_n bigint,
  ip_addr inet
);
```

Using `psql` and `\d public.test` correctly shows the use of the data type `test_domain`, the length of varchar(n) columns, and the precision and scale of numeric(p, s) columns.

```
sandbox=# \d public.test
             Table "public.test"
 Column  |         Type          | Modifiers
---------+-----------------------+-----------
 test_id | test_domain           |
 test_vc | character varying(15) |
 test_n  | numeric(15,3)         |
 big_n   | bigint                |
 ip_addr | inet                  |
```

This query against an information_schema view does *not* show the use of `test_domain` at all. It also doesn't report the details of varchar(n) and numeric(p, s) columns.

```
select column_name, data_type 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_catalog = 'sandbox'
  and table_schema = 'public'
  and table_name = 'test';
```

```
 column_name |     data_type
-------------+-------------------
 test_id     | character varying
 test_vc     | character varying
 test_n      | numeric
 big_n       | bigint
 ip_addr     | inet
```

You *might* be able to get all that information by joining other information_schema views, or by querying the system tables directly. `psql -E` might help with that.

The function `pg_typeof()` correctly shows the use of `test_domain`, but doesn't report the details of varchar(n) and numeric(p, s) columns.

```
select pg_typeof(test_id) as test_id, 
       pg_typeof(test_vc) as test_vc,
       pg_typeof(test_n) as test_n,
       pg_typeof(big_n) as big_n,
       pg_typeof(ip_addr) as ip_addr
from test;
```

```
   test_id   |      test_vc      | test_n  | big_n  | ip_addr
-------------+-------------------+---------+--------+---------
 test_domain | character varying | numeric | bigint | inet
```

Answer (score 6):

Pulling data type from `information_schema` is possible, but not convenient (requires joining several columns with a `case` statement). Alternatively one can use `format_type` built-in function to do that, but it works on internal type identifiers that are visible in `pg_attribute` but not in `information_schema`. Example

```
SELECT a.attname as column_name, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS data_type
FROM pg_attribute a JOIN pg_class b ON a.attrelid = b.relfilenode
WHERE a.attnum > 0 -- hide internal columns
AND NOT a.attisdropped -- hide deleted columns
AND b.oid = 'my_table'::regclass::oid; -- example way to find pg_class entry for a table
```

Based on https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/97834.

Comment: For posterity, with pg10 replace `b.relfilenode` with `b.oid`

Answer (score 2):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS

> `\gdesc` Shows the description (that is, the column names and data
> types) of the result of the current query buffer. The query is not
> actually executed; however, if it contains some type of syntax error,
> that error will be reported in the normal way.
>
> If the current query buffer is empty, the most recently sent query is
> described instead.

So you can `table student_details limit 0 \gdesc`
Output occupied less space than `\d`

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to find the datatypes of the specific field or all the fields from table.
Following is the list of all the ways.

- Using pg_typeof() Function
- Using \d Command
- Using SELECT Statement
- Using information_schema

#### Using pg_typeof() Function

pg_typeof() Function is a built-in function, it accepts column name as an argument and returns the data type.

**Example**

```
SELECT pg_typeof(bike_launch_date)
FROM public.bike_details
LIMIT 1;
```

LIMIT is set to 1 for avoiding repetitions.

##### Using \d Command

run the following command accompanied by the table name in order to get the data types of all the columns along with other information.

**Example**

```
\d table_name;
```

To further explore more remaining methods or get better understanding, explore the following article: [How to Check Column Types in PostgreSQL](https://commandprompt.com/education/how-to-check-column-types-in-postgresql/#:%7E:text=PostgreSQL%20provides%20several%20ways%20to,information_schema%20or%20pg_typeof()%20function.)