# How to get columns data types from arbitrary SQL select?

Tags: postgresql, types

I need to obtain column types from arbitrary SQL query. It's certainly possible, PgAdmin3 does it.

For example, given a query:

```
SELECT src.col, CAST(src.col AS varchar)
FROM (SELECT 'anything' AS col) AS src;
```

PgAdmin3 returns:

[image]

As you can see, column types are displayed basing on executed query, not on table schema.  How to obtain data types of columns in the result set programmatically?

Comment: I think this is the same question [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146705/select-datatype-of-the-field-in-postgres).  Does the query in that post help you out?

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky Not really. This accesses information schema which, AFAIU, stores information on persisted columns. I don't think I can use it to learn that some `COUNT(*)` is a `bigint` neither learn about applied type conversions. Or maybe I don't get purpose of information schema?

Comment: Oh.  So you want something like describe but for queries rather than tables.  If you are using a calling language like Java there are APIs to get this info from the metadata of the query.  I don't know how to do it at the command line (raw sql)

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky I'm using Ruby's ActiveRecord, yes, this approach sounds interesting. I got to investigate, although I was pretty sure it can be done with raw SQL.

Comment: the better solution is in the other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25369205/3494126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding function in the C client library is `PQftype`. It provides the type of any field from a query, as described in [Retrieving Query Result Information](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-SELECT-INFO), with other functions that apply on result fields, such as `PQftable` or `PQfsize`.
No EXPLAIN is needed, this information is shipped with every set of result coming back to a SQL client.

> PQftype
>
> ```
> Returns the data type associated with the given column number.
> ```
>
> The integer returned is the internal OID number of the type. Column
>   numbers start at 0.
>
> ```
>    Oid PQftype(const PGresult *res,
>                int column_number);
> ```
>
> You can query the system table pg_type to obtain the names and properties
>   of the various data types. The OIDs of the built-in data
>   types are defined in the file src/include/catalog/pg_type.h in the
>   source tree.

Additionally the OIDs of all types of a database can be obtained with:

```
select oid, typname from pg_type;
```

Other languages generally base their postgres support on libpq library, so they can call this function. They may or may not expose it depending on how complete their implementation is.

In the case of ruby, the `ruby-pg` driver apparently does it through [PGResult](http://rubydoc.info/github/ged/ruby-pg/PGresult)'s
`ftype(column_number)`  instance method. I don't know if this is of any help with ActiveRecord. Database-agnostic APIs tend to leave out functions that can't be easily abstracted across all the databases they support.

Answer (score 3):

Use the system catalog information function [**`pg_typeof()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE).

Comment: Yes, it does the job.  I'm going to approve unless someone provides simpler answer, that is one which works like `EXPLAIN …` where you pass whole query without modifying SELECT clause. I think that would be useful when SELECT clause is `*` like in `SELECT src.* FROM (SELECT CAST('wow' AS varchar) AS col) AS src;`.