# Why does Spring Data give me this reflection exception?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have some entities, repositories, and a predicate to handle a dynamic query generator. When I run a simple query I get an exception.

1. Why is there a reflection error?
2. Near the bottom of the trace it says that it cannot set Integer to String. I dont why thats there or if its related. All the values are Integer anyway so I dont even know where String is coming from.
3. The exception happens inside the call to findAll(). I assume Spring Data is working correctly and that I have configured something incorrectly. I just cant see what it is.

**StackTrace** (Edited to reduce post size)

```
    2016-11-11 11:52:05,405 [http-bio-8080-exec-13] ERROR com.etisoftware.lib.spring.web.controller.GlobalExceptionHandlerAdvice:34 - An uncaught exception occurred
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer com.etisoftware.workorderprinting.beans.cborg.WorkOrderOwner.number] by reflection for persistent property [com.etisoftware.workorderprinting.beans.cborg.WorkOrderOwner#number] : 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer com.etisoftware.workorderprinting.beans.cborg.WorkOrderOwner.number] by reflection for persistent property [com.etisoftware.workorderprinting.beans.cborg.WorkOrderOwner#number] : 1
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)

    Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer com.etisoftware.workorderprinting.beans.cborg.WorkOrderOwner.number] by reflection for persistent property [com.etisoftware.workorderprinting.beans.cborg.WorkOrderOwner#number] : 1
        at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:224)

        ... 89 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field com.etisoftware.workorderprinting.beans.cborg.WorkOrderOwner.number to java.lang.String
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:393)
        at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:67)
        ... 133 more
```

WorkOrder Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workorders")
public class WorkOrder
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "workorder_nbr")
  private Integer           number;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_nbr")
  private Subscriber        subscriber;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "wo_type")
  private WorkOrderType     type;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "pool_nbr")
  private WorkerPool        pool;

  @JoinColumn(name = "wo_status_nbr")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private WorkOrderStatus   status;

  @JoinColumn(name = "wo_owner_nbr")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private WorkOrderOwner    owner;

  @Column(name = "sched_date")
  private LocalDate         scheduleDate;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "slot_nbr")
  private TimeSlot slot;

  @Column(name = "auto_complete_date")
  private LocalDate         autoCompleteDate;

  @Column(name = "override")
  private Boolean           override;

  @JoinColumn(name = "wo_location_nbr")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Location          location;

  /*
   * Fetch the notes later in the service using this number because connecting the notes table is a pain
   */
  @Column(name = "wo_note_nbr")
  private Integer           noteNumber;
```

**WorkOrderOwner Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wo_owners")
public class WorkOrderOwner
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "wo_owner_nbr")
  private Integer number;

  @Column(name = "owner_id")
  private String  name;

  @Column(name = "email_address")
  private String  email_address;
```

**WorkOrderPredicates**

```
@Component
public class WorkOrderPredicates
{
  private static DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter     = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
  private static DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter     = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss");
  private static DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");

  public Predicate buildQueryFromSearchCriteria(PrintWorkOrderFormDto queryDto)
  {

    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    /*
     * TODO I think think this string "entity" which is a variable name is going to give us a problem.
     */
    PathBuilder<WorkOrder> entityPath = new PathBuilder<>(WorkOrder.class, "workOrder");

    for (SelectedCriteria criteria : queryDto.getCriteria().getRules())
    {
      assignValueAndOperator(predicates, entityPath, criteria);
    }

    /*
     * Per Chris, the queries will only have one group. That is, there will be a single condition [AND | OR] and then a
     * list of criteria.
     */
    if (queryDto.getCriteria().getCondition().equals(SelectionFilterCondition.AND))
    {
      for (Predicate p : predicates)
        builder.and(p);
    }
    else if (queryDto.getCriteria().getCondition().equals(SelectionFilterCondition.OR))
    {
      for (Predicate p : predicates)
        builder.or(p);
    }

    return builder;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  protected static void assignValueAndOperator(List<Predicate> predicates, PathBuilder<?> entityPath, SelectedCriteria criteria)
  {
    switch (criteria.getOperator())
    {
      case BETWEEN:
        List<LocalDate> values = (List<LocalDate>) criteria.getValue();
        LocalDate from = values.get(0);
        LocalDate to = values.get(1);
        // TODO how do we handle Time separately from Date.
        // TODO how do we handle DateTime
        predicates.add(entityPath.getDate(criteria.getField(), LocalDate.class).between(from, to));
        break;
      case BEGINS_WITH:
        predicates.add(entityPath.getString(criteria.getField()).like(criteria.getValue() + "%"));
        break;
      case NOT_BEGINS_WITH:
        predicates.add(entityPath.getString(criteria.getField()).notLike(criteria.getValue() + "%"));
        break;
      case CONTAINS:
        predicates.add(entityPath.getString(criteria.getField()).like("%" + criteria.getValue() + "%"));
        break;
      case NOT_CONTAINS:
        predicates.add(entityPath.getString(criteria.getField()).notLike("%" + criteria.getValue() + "%"));
        break;
      case ENDS_WITH:
        predicates.add(entityPath.getString(criteria.getField()).like("%" + criteria.getValue()));
        break;
      case NOT_ENDS_WITH:
        predicates.add(entityPath.getString(criteria.getField()).notLike("%" + criteria.getValue()));
        break;
      case EQUAL:
        predicates.add(entityPath.get(criteria.getField()).eq(extractAndCreateValueOfType(criteria.getValue(), criteria.getType())));
        break;
      case NOT_EQUAL:
        predicates.add(entityPath.get(criteria.getField()).ne(criteria.getValue()));
        break;
      case GREATER:
        // TODO this casting might not be right
        predicates.add(entityPath.getNumber(criteria.getField(), Integer.class).gt((Integer) criteria.getValue()));
        break;
      case LESS:
        // TODO this casting might not be right
        predicates.add(entityPath.getNumber(criteria.getField(), Integer.class).lt((Integer) criteria.getValue()));
        break;
      case LESS_OR_EQUAL:
        // TODO this casting might not be right
        predicates.add(entityPath.getNumber(criteria.getField(), Integer.class).loe((Integer) criteria.getValue()));
        break;
      case GREATER_OR_EQUAL:
        // TODO this casting might not be right
        predicates.add(entityPath.getNumber(criteria.getField(), Integer.class).goe((Integer) criteria.getValue()));
        break;
      case IN:
        /*
         * TODO this is causing a hibernate error because its trying to map an integer to a string. This type setting
         * below needs to be dynamic based on the selectedcriteria type
         */
        List<String> inValues = (List<String>) criteria.getValue();
        predicates.add(entityPath.get(criteria.getField(), String.class).in(inValues));
        break;
      case NOT_IN:
        List<String> notInValues = (List<String>) criteria.getValue();
        predicates.add(entityPath.get(criteria.getField(), String.class).in(notInValues).not());
        break;
      case IS_EMPTY:
        predicates.add(entityPath.getList(criteria.getField(), List.class).isEmpty());
        break;
      case IS_NOT_EMPTY:
        predicates.add(entityPath.getList(criteria.getField(), List.class).isNotEmpty());
        break;
      case IS_NOT_NULL:
        predicates.add(entityPath.get(criteria.getField()).isNotNull());
        break;
      case IS_NULL:
        predicates.add(entityPath.get(criteria.getField()).isNull());
        break;
      default:
        // TODO implement the default case
        break;
    }

  }

  @SuppressWarnings("cast")
  private static Object extractAndCreateValueOfType(Object valueObject, SelectionDataType selectionDataType)
  {
    Object value = null;
    switch (selectionDataType)
    {
      case BOOLEAN:
        // TODO
        break;
      case DATE:
        value = LocalDate.parse((String) valueObject, dateFormatter);
        break;
      case TIME:
        value = LocalDateTime.parse((String) valueObject, timeFormatter);
        break;
      case DATETIME:
        value = LocalDateTime.parse((String) valueObject, dateTimeFormatter);
        break;
      case DOUBLE:
        value = (Double) valueObject;
        break;
      case INTEGER:
        value = (Integer) valueObject;
        break;
      case STRING:
        value = (String) valueObject;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return value;
  }
```

**WorkOrderService fetch method**

```
 @Transactional(transactionManager = PersistenceConfigCbOrgAbstract.txMgrName, readOnly = true)
  protected List<WorkOrderDto> fetchWorkOrders(PrintWorkOrderFormDto queryParams, PrintStatus printStatus)
  {
    List<WorkOrderDto> dtos = new ArrayList<>();
    printStatus.setMessage("Fetching work orders");
    logger.debug("Query Params: " + queryParams);

    for (WorkOrder bean : workOrderRepository.findAll(workOrderPredicates.buildQueryFromSearchCriteria(queryParams)))
    {
      logger.debug(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(bean));
      WorkOrderDto dto = modelMapper.map(bean, WorkOrderDto.class);
      fetchAndAssignNotes(dto, bean.getNoteNumber());
      fetchAndAssignCreateDate(dto, bean.getNumber());
      fetchAndAssignPendingDeviceDtos(dto, bean.getNumber());
      fetchAndAssignPendingServiceDtos(dto, bean.getNumber());
      fetchAndAssignBilling(dto, bean.getNumber());

      try
      {
        dto.setCustomer(new CustomerDto());
        fetchAndAssignCustomer(dto);
      }
      catch (JsonParseException e)
      {
        logger.error("Could not parse customer information", e);
        printStatus.setMessage("Cannot fetch work orders. Please check the application log");
      }
      catch (JsonMappingException e)
      {
        logger.error("Could not map customer information", e);
        printStatus.setMessage("Cannot fetch work orders. Please check the application log");
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        logger.error("Got an IO exception while trying to map customer information", e);
        printStatus.setMessage("Cannot fetch work orders. Please check the application log");
      }

      logger.debug(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(dto, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE, Boolean.TRUE));
      printStatus.setRecordCount(printStatus.getRecordCount() + 1);
      dtos.add(dto);
    }

    return dtos;
  }
```

**wo_owners table**

```
CREATE TABLE wo_owners (
  wo_owner_nbr serial NOT NULL,
  owner_id nchar(20) NOT NULL,
  email_address nchar(80),
  PRIMARY KEY (wo_owner_nbr)
);
```

**workorders**

```
CREATE TABLE cborg2001:workorders (
  workorder_nbr serial NOT NULL,
  subscriber_nbr int,
  wo_type int,
  pool_nbr int,
  wo_status_nbr int,
  wo_owner_nbr int,
  wo_note_nbr int,
  sched_date date,
  slot_nbr int,
  auto_complete_date date,
  override int DEFAULT 0,
  wo_location_nbr int,
  PRIMARY KEY (workorder_nbr)
);
```

**QueryDSL Query**

```
com.querydsl.jpa.impl.JPAQuery:233 - select workOrder from WorkOrder workOrder where workOrder.scheduleDate = ?1
```

**Generated Query**

```
select
    workorder0_.workorder_nbr as workorde1_28_,
    workorder0_.auto_complete_date as auto_com2_28_,
    workorder0_.wo_location_nbr as wo_locat6_28_,
    workorder0_.wo_note_nbr as wo_note_3_28_,
    workorder0_.override as override4_28_,
    workorder0_.wo_owner_nbr as wo_owner7_28_,
    workorder0_.pool_nbr as pool_nbr8_28_,
    workorder0_.sched_date as sched_da5_28_,
    workorder0_.slot_nbr as slot_nbr9_28_,
    workorder0_.wo_status_nbr as wo_stat10_28_,
    workorder0_.subscriber_nbr as subscri11_28_,
    workorder0_.wo_type as wo_type12_28_ 
from
    workorders workorder0_ 
where
    workorder0_.sched_date=?
```

I used the following query to verify the datatypes of the columns.

```
SELECT ST.tabname, SC.colname, SC.coltype
FROM systables ST
JOIN syscolumns SC ON SC.tabid = ST.tabid
JOIN sys
WHERE ST.tabname="wo_owners";
```

It returns a result of:

```
tabname     wo_owner_nbr    coltype
wo_owners   wo_owner_nbr    262
wo_owners   owner_id    271
```

Informix coltypes are listed [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_025.htm).

```
262 - 256 = 6 = SERIAL
271 - 256 = 15 = NCHAR
```

Note* In DB-Access, an offset value of 256 is always added to these coltype codes because DB-Access sets SERIAL, SERIAL8, and BIGSERIAL columns to NOT NULL. [source](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_025.htm)

"Informix® supports the SERIAL, SERIAL8 and BIGSERIAL data types to produce automatic integer sequences. SERIAL is based on INTEGER (32 bit)" [source](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBJG3_2.5.0/com.ibm.gen_busug.doc/c_fgl_odiagmsv_010.htm)

Comment: Caused by is your friend here. Note the last Caused By in your stack trace. The field is set as an Integer in your Entity, but it appears to be coming from the DB as a String. This is obviously not ok.

Comment: I see now that you pointed out my above finding in your #2 point. This is absolutely related and means that in your database the column `workorder_nbr` is of type varchar or text or some other string type. Check your database table definition.

Comment: The  wo_owner_nbr in workorders is an int. The wo_owner_nbr in wo_owners is a serial.

I have edited the original post with this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact problem has nothing to do with Hibernate or Spring Data, its a problem with the way I was casting ArrayLists derived from Select elements on the UI. In WorkOrderPredicates I did this:

```
List<String> inValues = (List<String>) criteria.getValue();
```

That makes the values a String and it quite rightly cannot be assigned to an integer.

To make matters worse I later changed it to be something like this:

```
  if (criteria.getType().equals(SelectionDataType.INTEGER))
  {
    ArrayList<Integer> values = criteria.getValue();
    predicates.add(entityPath.get(criteria.getField()).in((values)));
  }
  else if (criteria.getType().equals((SelectionDataType.STRING)))
  {
     ArrayList<String> values = criteria.getValue();
    predicates.add(entityPath.get(criteria.getField()).in((evalues)));
  }
```

Here, because the generics are erased at RunTime the ArrayList is still an ArrayList < String > even through it looks like I am casting it.

My solution was to build new arrays like this:

```
  if (criteria.getType().equals(SelectionDataType.INTEGER))
  {
    predicates.add(entityPath.get(criteria.getField()).in((extractArrayListInteger(criteria))));
  }
  else if (criteria.getType().equals((SelectionDataType.STRING)))
  {
    predicates.add(entityPath.get(criteria.getField()).in((extractArrayListString(criteria))));
  }
```

**Methods to create new ArrayLists**

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static ArrayList<Integer> extractArrayListInteger(SelectedCriteria criteria)
  {
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object v : (ArrayList<Object>) criteria.getValue())
    {
      values.add(Integer.valueOf(v.toString()));
    }
    return values;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private static ArrayList<String> extractArrayListString(SelectedCriteria criteria)
  {
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String v : (ArrayList<String>) criteria.getValue())
    {
      values.add(v);
    }
    return values;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what we see it indeed looks like there are strings comming from the database, but you assure that the column is defined as an integer datatype. I just looked up the serial syntax and it seems to define and integer column plus a sequence in postgres.

Therefore I don't see a direct answer, but would like to suggest some things to track down the issue.

1. [use this to see the actual datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2146869/66686) the column has in the database.
2. load each JPA entity involved by id, to verify that the problem is actually about WorkOrderOwner
3. remove all attributes not relevant for the problem
4. change the `number` attribute to String and see if the problem goes away
5. Verify that you don't have getters and setters or that they have the proper datatype
6. Let us know about your findings

Comment: 2. I can load each JPA entity by ID using an integration test.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Transactional` annotation needs to be on a public method. You can either move the annotation to the public method that calls the protected method you have in your code snippet, or you can change your protected method to become public.

Comment: Thanks I should have caught that. I have fixed, and it actually solved a different problem I was having, but the main issue remains.