# how do I return the sql data types from my query in pgsql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

How do I return the data types of a query from a Postgres SQL database?

Is there a function I can put in my query to do this for a particular column, I am wondering this especially for calculated columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select datatype of the field in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146705/select-datatype-of-the-field-in-postgres)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a [function pg_typeof(any)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE).

For your case it can be used as:

```
SELECT pg_typeof(calculated_column_name) FROM (your_main_query_here);
```