# I am getting more than one result when checking column datatype postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using solutions provided in this question [Select datatype of the field in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146705/select-datatype-of-the-field-in-postgres) i am able to query the datatype of a column from my table however i am getting two different results on same column

```
SELECT column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE 
table_name = 'mytable' AND column_name = 'timestamp';

RESULTS
-------
column_name|data_type               |
-----------|------------------------|
timestamp  |timestamp with time zone|
timestamp  |character varying       |
```

How do i know for sure which is the correct datatype for that column. is it a `char...` or `time...` datatype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was maybe you had two tables with the same name in two different schemas.

Please change your query like that and add `table_schema`:

```sql
SELECT table_schema, column_name, data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE 
table_name = 'mytable' AND column_name = 'timestamp';
```